# Erro ao retornar vetor em um método

Tags: android

Não consigo retornar o vetor previsoes, o Android Studio não está aceitando. (incompatible Types)

```
public double MediaMovelSimples(double[] valores) {

    int i;
    int j;

    double[] previsoes = new double[valores.length - 3];

    int parametro = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < valores.length - 3; i++) {

        for (j = parametro; j < parametro + 3; j++) {

            previsoes[i] += valores[j];
        }
        parametro+=1;
    }
    return previsoes;
}
```

Comment: que erro aparece? coloque na pergunta

Comment: incompatible Types

Comment: Como você quer retornar um vetor de `double` se a assinatura do seu método retorna apenas um `double`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

o problema é que você está criando um método do tipo `double` e está retornando um array de double mude

```
public double MediaMovelSimples(double[] valores) {
```

para

```
public double[] MediaMovelSimples(double[] valores) {
```

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado!

Comment: Se você sanou suas dúvidas feche a pergunta por favor

Answer (score 1):

Aqui `public double MediaMovelSimples(double[] valores)` você declara e aqui `double[] previsoes`, as duas declarações tem que ser iguais. É o que o erro esta dizendo tipos incompatíveis.